# What does a high operating margin but a small but positive ROE imply about a company?

Tags: accounting

I'm analysing this company and am curious to what these figures mean about the operation of the company. Can someone comment on this?

Answer (score 1):

The operating margin deals with the ability for a company to make a profit above the costs of running the company and generating sales. While ROE is how much money the company makes relative to the shareholders equity. I'd be willing to bet that if a company has a small ROE then it also has a quite large P/E (price to earnings) ratio. This would be caused by the company's stock being bid up in relation to its earnings and may not necessarily be a bad thing. People expect the high operating margin to help drive increased revenues in the future, and are willing to pay a higher price now for when that day comes.